# Final maps with the same domain

Tags: order-theory, nets

Let $\mathbb D$ and $\mathbb E$ be two directed sets, then a map $f:\mathbb D\to \mathbb E$ is said to be **final**,if for any $e\in E$ there exists some $d\in D$ such that $f(d')\geq e$ whenever $d'\geq d.$

**Question:** For two arbitrary directed sets $\mathbb D$ and $\mathbb E,$ does there exists a third directed set $\mathbb A$ such that there exists two final maps $f_1:\mathbb A\to \mathbb D$ and $f_2:\mathbb A\to \mathbb E?$  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems like this third directed set would act like the categorical product of the first two.. is that true ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{A}$ be the family of finite subsets of $\mathbb{D}\cup \mathbb{E}$ ordered by inclusion. This is clearly a directed set. Let $f_1:\mathbb{A}\rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ be a function such that, for every finite set $F\in\mathbb{A}$, $f_1(F)\geq x$ for every $x\in F \cap \mathbb{D}$. This can be done using definable choice because $\mathbb{D}$ is directed.

Try to define $f_2$ analogously and prove that this works.

Comment: Excellent! BTW, I think it would be better to define $\mathbb A:=\left\{X\cup Y|\ X\ \text{is a finite subset of } \mathbb D,\ Y\ \text{is a finite subset of } \mathbb E\right\}, $ in order to avoid the case $F\cap \mathbb D=\emptyset$ or $F\cap\mathbb E=\emptyset. $

Comment: For my supervisor zero is still a finite cardinality. Anyhow the definition I gave still works if $F \cap \mathbb{D}$ is empty. In that case $f_1(F)$ would just be any element in $\mathbb{D}$.